# If $ U $ is an open set, and we have a closed disk contained in $ U $, Can we find bigger open disk that contains the smaller disk?

Tags: general-topology

Assume $ U $ is an open subset, and assume $ D=D(a,r) $ is a disk such that $\overline{D} \subset U$ (The closure of D contained in U ). Can we find  $ \varepsilon>0 $ such that $D(a,r+\varepsilon) \subseteq U $ ? (an open disk with radius $r+\varepsilon$ which obviously contains D )

Furthermore, can we even find such disk, that even its closure contained in $ U$ ?

If so, how can we prove it?

I started to learn complex analysis and it seems like the author using topology results without a proof, and I havent learned topology yet, so im curious about this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like it is equivalent to the T4 (normal) separation axiom, which holds for $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: They key is that $\bar D$ is compact, not merely closed. In general the distance between a closed set (here, $U^c$) and a compact set (here, $\bar D$) is positive, so you can enlarge $\bar D$ by some small amount without touching $U^c$.

Comment: @RobArthan All metric spaces are T4. A separation in your example is given by the open upper/lower half planes.

Comment: @DuncanRamage: of course. I had a brainstorm and my comment was wrong.

Comment: @RobArthan It was a very compelling example and had me worried for a moment! I suppose the take away from it is that you can't "uniformly" separate them, in some sense. I can't say I know enough about metric spaces to say if that's a well defined idea, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true because, in the metric space of complex numbers, bounded closed sets, like the boundary of a closed disk, enjoy a useful topological property called [compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space). A compact subset $X$ has the property that if you have $X \subseteq \bigcup_i O_i$ where the $O_i$ are a collection of open sets (e.g., open disks), then there is a finite subcollection of the $O_i$, say $O_{i_1}, \ldots, O_{i_n}$ such that $X \subseteq O_{i_1} \cup \ldots \cup O_{i_n}$. In your example, you can pick a small open disk $D_x$ around each $x$ in the boundary  $\delta(\overline{D})$ of $\overline{D}$ such that $D_x \subseteq U$. You then have that $\delta(\overline{D}) \subseteq \bigcup_x D_x$ and hence, by compactness, $\delta(\overline{D}) \subseteq D_{x_1} \cup \ldots \cup D_{x_n}$ for some finite set $x_i$ of elements of $\delta(\overline{D})$. If you now take $\varepsilon$ to be the minimum of the radii of the disks $D_{x_1}, \ldots, D_{x_n}$, you will have $D(a, r + \varepsilon) \subseteq U$.

Comment: The maximum radius? Doesn't seem like this would work. Example: suppose $U$ is the open disc centered at origin of radius $2$, $D$ the open disc of radius $1$, and suppose $D_0$ is a disc of radius $1.5$ (I'm mimicing the notation $D_x$ you use). Then, by compactness, we have a finite subcover, which could potentially consist of the single open disc $D_0$. In this case, $D(a,r+\epsilon)=D(0,1+1.5)=D(0,2.5)$ is most certainly not contained in $U$. This also shows taking the minimum of the radii wouldn't work.

Comment: The way I'd proceed is to let $f(x)=\text{dist}(x,U^c)$, defined for all $x\in \Bbb{R}^2$. This is a continuous function which attains a minimum on the compact set $\overline{D}$, and this minimum has to be strictly positive since $\overline{D}$ is a compact set disjoint from the closed set $U^c$.